# BeanItem not updating associated Field more than one, when changing property by hand

Tags: vaadin

I'm scratching my head, trying to work out why a BeanItem's property isn't updating the component Field's value - more than once :(.

```
class MyComponent extends CustomComponent {
    TextField firstNames
    BeanItem<MyObject> bean = new BeanItem<MyObject>(new MyObject())

    MyComponent() {
        Layout layout = new FormLayout()
        setCompositionRoot(layout)

        firstNames = new TextField("First Names")
        layout.addComponent(firstNames)

        FieldGroup binder = new FieldGroup(bean)
        binder.bindMemberFields(this)
    }

    void setFromAccount(MyObject newObject) {
        bean.getItemProperty("firstNames").setValue(newObject.firstNames)
    }
}
```

The first time I call `setFromAccount` the value of the firstNames text field is updated on screen. The second time it isn't, and the first value persists.

Does anyone know what's going on? I thought that whenever I set the value on the underlying property everything was updated through internal listeners. Why is it only happening the first time?

Comment: just to be clear on the number one here: c'tor -> works, first call to setFromAccount -> works, second call to setFromAccount -> value not updated? or is just setFromAccount never working?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Digging through the property in the debugger the second time around it appears like the field's update listener is no longer registered. :/

Comment: @cfrick, did you have any ideas?